# Edit Virtuemart Accordion Menu

Tags: joomla, accordion, virtuemart

I am using Virtuemart Accordion Menu from http://www.ladadeal.com/virtuemart-accordion-menu
But now i want to display all level 2 category when open website. 
Is there any idea?
Thanks

Comment: In your module menu positions the last flag show under menus is set to YES?

Comment: it doesn't work.